# How to Select a Andorid device from a list of connected Devices to open an application using Appium

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

I am Testing an android app on multiple real devices like the Samsung S6 and S7 and both are connected to the machine at the same time.
Using Appium library within Robot Framework; `Open Application` keyword always opens the application which comes first in the list of "adb devices".

Key word used :

```
Open Application  ${APPIUM_SERVER_URL}  alias=MyMv1 platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}   platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION} deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}   appPackage=${app_package_name}  appActivity=${activity} automationName=appium
```

It seems `deviceName` is not working, and I can give any value to it.

Library Version Used :

```
robotframework==3.0.2
robotframework-appiumlibrary==1.4.3
```

Comment: Within your code, you only have one space ` ` between `alias=MyMv1` and `platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}` You are also not consistent with the spacing (some times using 2 spaces, 4 spaces, 1 space, etc) You need a minimum of 2 spaces but its recommend that you use 4.

Comment: Also one space between `platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}` and  `deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}` And again - one space between `appActivity=${activity}` and `automationName=appium`

Comment: @Goralight Thanks for the comment. I am using robot plugin in eclipse and spacing is managed by that only. I am pressing tab and some time it is putting 2 space and sometimes 4. But the code is working fine without any syntax error.